# Keep list of hashs

Tags: string, hash, md5

I am working on a small project to keep my skills from completely rusting

I am generating a lot of hashes(in his case md5) and I need to check if I've seen that hash before so I wanted to keep it in a list

whats the best way to list them that I can look if they exist in pior to doing calculations

Answer (score 2):

The hash itself is already a key of sorts. Your best bet is a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). In a properly implemented hash table, you can check for the existence of a key in constant time. Common hash table implementations with this feature are C# Dictionaries, Python's `dict` type, PHP `array` (which are actually Maps, not arrays), Perl's hashes `%` and Ruby's `Hash`. If you included details of what language you're working in, an example wouldn't be too hard to lookup.

Comment: +1 / for C++, [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)...